# enque jquery scripts in wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I can't get any enqueue_script to work, here is my code (which is in my plugin file)

```
function load_custom_wp_admin_style() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker', '', array('jquery'));
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```

Where am i going wrong? I can't seem to load my own scripts either

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
```

I am now getting jquery-ui script loaded, but the datepicker script is not being loaded

Answer (score 0):

jquery-ui-datepicker is bundled with WordPress (recent versions) so you don't need to tell it anything more than the script handle.

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
```

But: "can't get it to work" means what exactly? Have you looked in the page source and not found the script being loaded? Or it loads, but has no CSS styling it? I suspect your problem is the latter, because you aren't enqueuing any CSS for the datepicker (above, at least).

Now, the problem is that WordPress doesn't actually bundle in any supporting CSS for the datepicker, since WordPress itself doesn't use it. So, you need to either:

- add some supporting CSS to your admin stylesheets
- enqueue a compatible standard jquery-ui theme, e.g. from a CDN

For the latter, I [blogged about that](http://snippets.webaware.com.au/snippets/load-a-nice-jquery-ui-theme-in-wordpress/) a while ago; here's some code that should handle that for you; add it to your function, above.

```
global $wp_scripts;

// get registered script object for jquery-ui
$ui = $wp_scripts->query('jquery-ui-core');

// tell WordPress to load the Smoothness theme from Google CDN
$url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/{$ui>ver}/themes/smoothness/jquery.ui.all.css";
wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-smoothness', $url, false, null);
```

That loads the whole enchilada, but you might want to pare it back to just the CSS that the datepicker needs.

Edit: to get the datepicker script on an older version of WordPress which doesn't bundle the datepicker script with the other jquery-ui scripts, the easiest solution is to install [Use Google Libraries](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/use-google-libraries/). This plugin will replace the local jquery scripts with Google's CDN hosted versions, and all jquery-ui scripts will be downloaded as a single (well-cached!) script.

Comment: wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');

I can see that jquery-ui is now being loaded, but datepicker is not?

Comment: You only need to enqueue jquery-ui-datepicker, because jquery and jquery-ui-core are prerequisites.

Comment: Just calling jquery-ui-datepicker doesn't load ui-core for me?

Comment: What version of WordPress are you running? It was only bundled into WordPress recently (like 3.4 or something)

Comment: Ahh, there is the problem, i am running 3.2.1. How should i proceed without updating wordpress right now?

Comment: The easiest way for you to get the full compliment of jquery-ui libraries is to install the [Use Google Libraries plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/use-google-libraries/), because it will replace all jquery-ui individual scripts with a single full-library script, including the datepicker, and it will version-match with your WordPress version.